# Why does suspend in 19.04 takes 30 seconds?

Tags: suspend, 19.04

This question seems to have been asked in various forms, but so far I haven't see any real solution! I thought it might be worthwhile to explain exactly what is happening on my system under Ubuntu 19.04 in case that might throw some additional light on the problem...

I've tried various approaches to suspending my system, including:

1) The 3rd party Gnome extension "Suspend button"
2) Holding down the Alt key to force the Power Off button to become a Suspend key
3) Assigning a keyboard shortcut for command "/bin/systemctl suspend"
4) Tapping the power button on the desktop computer

In cases 1-3:

- The screen blanks IMMEDIATELY and stays blank for about 2 seconds.
- The screen un-blanks and returns to the state it was in before trying to suspend.
- While the screen is un-blanked the system is active and can be used.
- Exactly 30 seconds after initiating the 'suspend' the screen goes blank again AND the system goes into suspend mode.

In case 4 the screen blanks immediately AND the system goes into suspend mode at once.

This problem is not a real "big deal" since I can just hit the shortcut key as mentioned in case 3, above, and then walk away from the system. It would be a bit more satisfying, though, if the 'suspend' took place immediately instead of being delayed for 30 seconds!

Any suggestions/thoughts would be greatly appreciated!